# define global path in code igniter except base_url

Tags: php, codeigniter

How could i define another global path except base-url in codeigniter
like my `base url` is like `localhost/folder_name`
while i want to use one another path like

```
localhost/another_folder/
```

Comment: Its not clear what you asking. But why not use `$config['new_settings']='localhost/another_folder/file_name';` and get it as `$this->config->item('new_settings')`

Comment: you can also define that path as a constant variable : define('GLOBLE_PATH','localhost/another_folder/file_name'); in the config/constant.php

Comment: Dear Shaiful Islam
will you please tell me how coul i use this path in every page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IN the config file define

```
$config['variable']= 'your path'
```

use it just like

```
$this->config->item('variable');
```

I think this will help you according you requirement

Answer (score 2):

You can also set a `global path` like `base_url` in Codeigniter like the `global variable`,

You can define `global path` in `application/config/constants.php` file like:

```
define("globel_variable","http://localhost/my_site");
```

Which can be accessible throughout all pages, ie; `controllers, models and views`

To display the global value,

```
echo globel_variable;
```

Comment: How is this uses in another pages

Comment: @user3287040 Just use globel_variable. Like, echo globel_variable; No need for $ sign :)